# DataBindings betwen two class

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

**Object:** Use DataBindings between three class

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2012, C#, WindowsForms

**Error:** DataBindings not work in my classes

**Expected results:**

Objects:

- Height: Quantity
- Base: Quantity
- Area: Formulate
- AreaResult: Result

DataBindings:

```
Area.DataBindings.Add("H",Height,"Q");
Area.DataBindings.Add("B",Base,"Q");
AreaResult.DataBindings.Add("Display",Area,"Calculation");

Height.Q = 5;
Base.Q = 6;
```

Should produce that `Area.Calculation` set to 30 and `AreaResult.Display` too.

***Class Quantity code:***

```
public class Quantity:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public Nullable<decimal> Q
   {
      get{ return this._q;}
      set
         {
            this._q = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Q");
         }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
   {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

***Class Formulate code:***

```
public class Formulate: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
   public Nullable<decimal> H
    {
        get { return this._h; }
        set
        {
            this._h = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("H");
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _h;


    public Nullable<decimal> Q
    {
        get { return this._q; }
        set
        {
            this._q = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Q");
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _h;


    public Nullable<decimal> Calculation
    {
        get { return this._calculation; }
        set
        {
            this._calculation = H/Q;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Caltulation");
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _calculation;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

***Class Result code:***

```
public class Result:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public Nullable<decimal> Display
   {
      get{ return this._display;}
      set
         {
            this._display = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Display");
         }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
   {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: Maybe not the root of the issue, but did you notice the typo in NotifyPropertyChanged("Caltulation"); this will return to byte you later.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
public class Formulate: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
   public Nullable<decimal> H
    {
        get { return this._h; }
        set
        {
            this._h = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("H");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Calculation");
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _h;


    public Nullable<decimal> Q
    {
        get { return this._q; }
        set
        {
            this._q = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Q");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Calculation");
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _h;


    public Nullable<decimal> Calculation
    {
        get { return _h == null || _q == null ? null : _h.Value / _q.Value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answers, Displays error classes: no definition of databinding

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion @Murven, but I get the same error "No definition of databinding"